# Proving Functions are bijective and determining inverse functions.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

So the question in mind is

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $$f(x)= \begin{cases}\frac{3x+2}{x-1}&x\neq1\\3&x=1\end{cases}$$
>
> Show that $f$ is a bijection and determine the inverse function.

I've managed to show that $f$ is injective but I'm struggling with proving that it's surjective. Just to check that I'm on the right track, is $x=\frac{2+y}{y-3}$ when $y\in\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. When $y\neq3$, if we let $z=\frac{y+2}{y-3}$, then $f(z)=y$. And, when $y=3$, $f(1)=y$. So, for all $y\in\mathbb R$, there exist $z\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(z)=y$. This is surjectivity.

So, the inverse is given by $$g(y)=\begin{cases}\frac{y+2}{y-3}&y\neq3\\1&y=3\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

You are on the correct track. **Whenever $x$ is not $1$,** the corresponding $x$ can be given in terms of its output $y$ by

$$x = \frac{2+y}{y-3}$$

Obviously, whenever $y$ is not $3$, this $x$ is defined. Thus, for all real $y \ne 3$, you can find a corresponding input $x$ such that $f(x)=y$. To find that $x$, just use the above equation.

This gives surjectivity on $\Bbb R \setminus \{3\}$.

To get surjectivity on all of $\Bbb R$, it is sufficient to note that your function defines $f(1)=3$, giving you that last missing point. Of course, it also gives you the value of the inverse function when evaluated at $3$.